# How to navigate between views in storyboard without using Navigationbar or Tab Bar

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

I have three UIViews in my storyboard, how can I navigate between them with **push** like animation without using **Navigationbar** or **Tab Bar**? I have my custom buttons on views. 
Control-click and drag does not work with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Push segues can
only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.
```

Comment: Maysam, does my answer below solve your problem?

Comment: I have not tried it yet, kinda busy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can present/dismiss VCs without using Navigation Controller.

Notice the terminology: push/pop is used for VCs on the Navigation Controller stack, present/dismiss is for VCs on other VCs (not on a Navigation Controller stack).

There are a couple of way to present a VC on top of another VC and it depends on whether that VC exists on your SB as well:

1- If the VC does not exist in your IB and you are just creating and presenting the VC programmatically, you can do:

```
 MyUIViewControllerSubclass *myLittleSubclass=[[MyUIViewControllerSubclass alloc]init];
myLittleSubclass.view.frame=self.view.frame; //this is for exmaple only
[self presentViewController:myLittleSubclass animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With the above, you obviously would have to add the MyUIViewControllerSubclass Objective C class first to your project (using add files) and import it to whichever class you are putting the above code.

Later to dismiss it, you can use the following code from the MyUIViewControllerSubclass class itself.

```
 [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

2- If you have already added the MyUIViewControllerSubclass Objective C class to your project (using add files) but you intend to use the IB to design it and you have added the VC in the IB and changed its class in the IB to MyUIViewControllerSubclass, you can then use this code:

```
mySubclass *myLittleSubclass=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"theVC"];
[self presentViewController:myLittleSubclass animated:YES completion:nil];
```

You can dismiss same as above.
Make sure that you click on the VC in SB and in the identity inspector, put the SB ID as "theVC" and check "Use SB ID".

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the middle code example, self.parentViewController should be self.presentingViewController if your are running in iOS 5+. ParentViewController comes through null now.

Answer (score 0):

The push animation is only supported when using a `UINavigationController` inside the parent view. You can embed your view controller in one *edit->embed in->navigation controller* in IB, and hide the navbar. This may provide the functionality you desire.